# Count in SQL server

Tags: sql, count

```
select
hotel.hotel_name 'Hotel Name',
Address 'Address',
Description 'Description',
Contact_No 'Contact Number'
from hotel, customer_profile, booking_details where
customer_profile.email = booking_details.email
and hotel.hotel_name = booking_details.hotel_name
and booking_details.email = 'davidho@yahoo.com'
order by 1
```

I can't add images /:

So for example currently my result is

```
+-----------------------+
| Name   | Address      |
+-----------------------+
| Hotel1 | Beach Road1  | 
| Hotel2 | Beach Road2  |
| Hotel2 | Beach Road2  |
+-----------------------+
```

I want it to remove the duplicates, and add a new column "Number of times" which indicate how many times it appeared.

I want it to be

```
+------------------------------------+
| Name   | Address     | No of Times |
+------------------------------------+
| Hotel1 | Beach Road1 | 1           |
| Hotel2 | Beach Road2 | 2           |
+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: As a note, your current result doesn't match the current query, because one has two columns and the other four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use for your examples `group by` clause a below

```
select
hotel.hotel_name "Hotel Name",
Address, count(1) "No of Times"
from hotel, customer_profile, booking_details where
customer_profile.email = booking_details.email
and hotel.hotel_name = booking_details.hotel_name
and booking_details.email = 'davidho@yahoo.com'
group by hotel.hotel_name, Address   
order by 1
```

Comment: Your code worked! But what I don't understand is (sorry I'm still learning), why do we have to put "Address" in
"group by hotel.hotel_name, Address"

Comment: @LeeJunWei In the group by you have to include fields which are not used in aggregate function (count,max,min etc.)

Answer (score 1):

First, learn proper `join` syntax, don't use single quote for column names, and use column aliases for all columns.  Here is what I think your current query is doing.

```
select h.hotel_name as HotelName, h.Address. h.Description
       cp.Contact_No 
from booking_details bd join
     hotel h
     on h.hotel_name = bd.hotel_name join
     customer_profile cp
     on cp.email = bd.email
where bd.email = 'davidho@yahoo.com'
order by 1;
```

Next, to solve your question, just use `group by`.  You can also eliminate the join to `customer_profile`, because I don't think that table gets used:

```
select h.hotel_name as HotelName, h.Address. count(*) as NumberOfTimes
from booking_details bd join
     hotel h
     on h.hotel_name = bd.hotel_name 
where bd.email = 'davidho@yahoo.com'
order by 1;
```